# Vetor de array possui "n" elementos, mas lenght retorna "n+1" em C

Tags: c, array, string, concatenação-de-string

Olá,

Tenho a seguinte dúvida: Eu tenho um vetor e tenho certeza que é passado para ele apenas um elemento através do seguinte loop:

```
char uid[1];
while(indice1 < indice2){
    printf("Valor de indice 1 %d, indice 2 %d\n", indice1, indice2);
    uid[indice0] = recvline[indice1];
    ++indice1; ++indice0;
}
```

Imprimindo os valores dos índices eles são respectivamente 11 e 12.

No entanto, quando concateno essa string com outra através da função strcat ou retorno o tamanho dela usando (int)strlen(uid), o tamanho é 2.

Acredito que o elemento '\0' deveria ser suprimido na concatenação ou na contagem de elementos.

Alguma solução?

Obrigado!

Comment: basta fazeres `lenght - 1`

Comment: Remover o \0 do final fará com que sua string exiba o conteúdo do restante dos campos vazios. Ex: Se sua string tem tamanho 11 e o array 30 vai aparecer símbolos quaisquer nas outras 19 posições até o final do array.